# Email Validation to avoid duplicate entry within two items Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am having two items:

1. P1_email
2. p2_emails

Here I want to validate the email ids, the same email ids should not enter with these items.

If I enter same email id in both items, it should raise an error:

> its not possible to enter the same email id in both place.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to create **validation** on P2_EMAILS item. Choose `PL/SQL Function (returning error text)`. Code to be used:

```
if :P1_EMAIL = :P2_EMAILS then 
   return ('It is not possible to enter the same email ID in both places');
end if;
```

Note that this won't handle *invalid* e-mail addresses (such as "little@foot@gmail@com"), NULLs etc. - as I said, it is the *simplest* way to do what you asked.